# In MUIv5, TextField component has unwanted whitespace in the corners

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using `MaterialUI_v5` and have added a `TextField` component to a `Paper` component.

I have styled the `Paper` component background to `green`.

I have styled the `Textfield` component to `white`.

There is unwanted whitespace in the corners of the `Textfield` component, which I want to be green (image below).

The `Textfield` component has the following props:

```
<TextField className={styles.input} label="First Name" variant="outlined" size="small" />
```

with styling being:

```
.input{
    background-color: white;
    width: 400px;
}
```

[image: Textfield with green background and unwanted white corners]

Answer (score 0):

The input container has a border radius applied. Try updating the container styles rather than the input by changing the class from `.input` to `.MuiOutlinedInput-root`

```css
.MuiOutlinedInput-root {
  background-color: white;
  width: 400px;
}
```